# How to export chart to PDF, now the view is too small

Tags: javascript, pdf, chart.js

trying to export my CartJS to PDF file using JavaScript.

I've found a solution for jsPDF ,and its working but the generated PDF view is too small.
This is my chart:
[image]

and this is generated file:
[image]

My code:

```
html2canvas($("#canvasChart"), {
            onrendered: function(canvas) {         
                var imgData = canvas.toDataURL({
                    format: 'jpeg',
                    quality: 0.9 // compression works now!
                });  

                var doc = new jsPDF("l", "mm", "a4");
                doc.addImage(imgData, 'PNG', 100, 100);
                doc.save('sample-file.pdf');
            }
        });
```

I will be very thankful for help and explanation what I am doing wrong. 
Thanks in advance,

Comment: This might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34897515/chartjs-jspdf-blurry-image, and the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/crabbly/kL68ey5z/

Comment: Wow, it's working! thanks a lot!