# Canvas charts is blurry when download as PDF

Tags: angular, pdf, canvas, html5-canvas, jspdf

### 2nd Update:

***Thanks again for everyone who commented/answered my question***

**Problem solved:**
I am not able to make canvas image looks better on the generated PDF and the due date of the project is closing, finally, I decided to move the "PDF Report" feature from Front-End(Angular) to Back-End(python), I have posted an answer(**not really an answer for my own question, but more like a solution**)

### Update after a couple of days search:

I have replaced Chart.js with Echarts but the blurry issue still exists. I did a lot of search on jsPDF and Canvas blurry online, it seems like the canvas settings need to be customized, unfortunately, I have no clue how to achieve it.

How looks in broswer:
[image]

When download as PDF:
[image]

### Original Question:

I have an Angular project which is required to download PDF for graph data. I choose Chart.js and jspdf which works well. When I print 2 charts in one page, the resolution is okay but when I try to print 3 charts on the same page, the texts are blurry. I have read this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34897515/chartjs-jspdf-blurry-image) but not figured out how to make resolution better when having multiple charts.

HTML Code:

```
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="card card-chart">
      <div class="card-header">
        <h5 class="card-title">Cervical Lateral Flexion</h5>
        <!--<p class="card-category">Line Chart</p>-->
      </div>
      <div class="card-body">
        <canvas id="cervicalLateralFlexion"></canvas>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Typescript Code:

```
  public static buildChart(doc, selector, title, yHeight) {
    let height = yHeight;
    const canvas = document.querySelector(selector) as HTMLCanvasElement;
    doc.setFontSize(h5);
    doc.text(leftMargin, yHeight, title);
    const canvasImage = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
    height += margin;
    doc.addImage(canvasImage, 'PNG', leftMargin, height);
  }
```

Can anyone help? How to solve this issue? Thanks in advance!
Image 1 is how it looks on web page and image 2 is PDF file.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Looks like the image dimensions are changed in second image. Blurry might be bcoz the image is stretched.

Comment: which jspdf version You are using?

Comment: The problem is bilinear filtering on the PDF copy of the image due to its size settings do not match the image pixel size. Your call to `doc.addImage` looks like the wrong arguments. `doc.addImage(img, format, xPos, yPos, width, height, alias)` Ensure that the canvas resolution matches the display size in the PDF doc. Try `doc.addImage(canvasImage, 'PNG', leftMargin, yPos, canvas.width, canvas.height, "graph")`  You will have to create the `yPos`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update on May 10th, 2020**
I have recorded a couple of videos on how to build PDF report using Weasyprint and Plotly, you can find details here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hjWTCYPy7oU&t=1s

**Update on Feb 3rd, 2020:**

I have found that `Plotly` is really amazing when export static images, highly recommended. See images I have built and you can compare it with my original question post images:
[image]
A couple of features:

- Images can be saved as SVG or PNG. No worry about the blurry issue anymore!
- it is easy to customize the theme/style
- You can add any shape on the graph, see the blue vertical line, you can draw triangle, rectangle(see the filled gray area) and any other shapes you want to.
- It supports multiple languages: JS, Python, and R.

---

**Original Post in 2019:**

**Thanks all for whom answered my question, I really appreciate your help** 
I spent more than 2 weeks on jsPDF + Chart.js but still not figuring out how to print PDF with canvas images properly.

This project is new, the languages/tools/dependencies are not restricted. To make the project done on time I switch the PDF report from Front-End(Angular) to Back-End(Python).
Now it took me 2 days to complete the PDF.

sources I used to generate PDF report and Charts:

- Weasyprint https://weasyprint.org/
- Pygal http://pygal.org/en/stable/

Many thanks to **Weasyprint** for making generating PDF documents with HTML and CSS productive!
Here's the PDF I have been generated:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the height and width in `addImage`

```
doc.addImage(canvasImage, 'PNG', leftMargin, height, "IMAGE-WIDTH-HERE", "IMAGE-HEIGHT-HERE");
```

If you don't know the image dimensions try something like this.

```
function getImageDimensions(file) {
  return new Promise (function (resolved, rejected) {
    var i = new Image()
    i.onload = function(){
      resolved({w: i.width, h: i.height})
    };
    i.src = file
  })
}

public static buildChart(doc, selector, title, yHeight) {
    let height = yHeight;
    const canvas = document.querySelector(selector) as HTMLCanvasElement;
    doc.setFontSize(h5);
    doc.text(leftMargin, yHeight, title);

    const canvasImage = canvas.toDataURL('image/png, 1.0');

    let dimensions = await getImageDimensions(canvasImage);

    height += margin;
    doc.addImage(canvasImage, 'PNG', leftMargin, height, dimensions.w, dimensions.h);
  }
```

`getImageDimensions` function copied from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49159728/1188322), this function uses Promises since we need synchronous behavior in your scenario.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I have tried it before asking the question but it didn't help...

Comment: I searched online, it seems like it's Chart.js issue. i will replace it with Echarts tomorrow and see whether it helps. Thanks again

Comment: Try html2pdf,  it uses jsPDF internally. I use that to convert D3 charts to pdf. Its very good https://github.com/eKoopmans/html2pdf

Comment: I have tried your latest update but no chart when saving to PDF.

Comment: Can you plz share the code. I have used it with react, not with angular, but that should not be a prob. html2pdf pulls contents from DOM

Answer (score 2):

This is a workaround, not a direct solution to the jsPDF issues described.  I was faced with the exact same issue: jsPDF, blurriness for charts and angular.

Hopefully, I'm not straying too far off topic but I thought this would be valuable for some.

The workaround: **node + [puppeteer](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer)**

puppeteer is a headless chrome browser that works under any environment (even linux terminal) and can render a web page into an image or PDF.

```
    import * as puppeteer from "puppeteer";

    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({});
    const page = await browser.newPage();

    await page.goto("https://google.com", { waitUntil: 'networkidle2' });
    await page.setViewport({ width: 1250, height: 3950 });
    await page.screenshot({ path: 'hourly_report.png' });
    await browser.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using [puppeteer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/puppeteer) for taking the screenshot in image or pdf format then you need to scale the image using `deviceScaleFactor` option, by default it is set to 1. Its min value is 1 and the max is 5. By setting it, both the image as well as pdf would be scaled up in quality. Check out this [issue](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/571) for more details on this. Attaching the code below:

```js
const page = await browser.newPage();
await page.setViewport({ width: 800, height: 800, deviceScaleFactor: 3 });
```

P.S. Setting *width* and *height* to viewport wouldn't have any effect on the size of image/pdf.