# Export chart to pdf in high quality. Blurry zoom

Tags: javascript, image, pdf, canvas, chart.js

How can i export some charts make with chart.js library into PDF without lose quality. I want that i zoom in pdf the image doesn't show blurry.

PDF image

[image: PDF image]

I'm trying build canvas in position -2000 with different size. But the problem persist...

Comment: Have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/a/45129542/2836621